# Error in names(output) <- `*vtmp*` : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]

Tags: r, vector, dplyr

I am currently trying to run functions from the `codyn` package to calculate species turnover over time.

I am using the function `turnover`, but I keep encountering this error:

```
spTurnover <- turnover(df = turnover_dat, 
                         time.var = "year", 
                         species.var = "species", 
                         abundance.var = "abundance",
                       replicate.var = "site")
```

```
Error in names(output) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

A screenshot of the tibble below:

[image]

A dput of my data is provided below:

```
dput(head(turnover_dat))
structure(list(species = c("Accipiter badius", "Accipiter badius", 
"Accipiter badius", "Accipiter badius", "Accipiter badius", "Accipiter badius"
), site = c("BVLR", "BVLR", "BVLR", "BVLR", "KKTG", "KKTG"), 
    year = c(1850, 1900, 1950, 2021, 1850, 1900), abundance = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: can you show your code for testing

Comment: @akrun Updated it to show code and a screenshot of what the tibble looks like.

Comment: Any solution @akrun?

Comment: How may rows you have in the original dataset

Comment: 4860 rows - this is after I joined four dataframes using full_join() - so it essentially added NAs in certain rows where that value was not found. @akrun

Comment: I was able to get similar error with the example data in their documentation after subsetting i.e. why I asked. (after changing the first element of year to around 1850s

Comment: I see - could this be an issue with the function in the first place? @akrun

Comment: I think so.  As they are using `Map` in multiple places

Comment: You could use `traceback` or `debugonce` to pinpoint the line where error occurred.

Comment: I used traceback and it's suggesting:                                                              
 traceback()
3: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2: lapply(X, FUN = turnover_allyears, time.var, species.var, abundance.var, 
       metric)
1: turnover(df = turnover_dat, time.var = "year", species.var = "species", 
       abundance.var = "abundance", replicate.var = "site")

Comment: As you already posted on their github page, I would wait for the authors  tosuggest the remedy for it.